# Querying STRUCT elements in an ARRAY (Bigquery)

Tags: google-bigquery

Hi guys need help on this example on the official documentation: I cant seem to get similar results as the one on the documentation page even after copy n pasting the code there

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#querying_nested_arrays

output according to the page:

[image]

```
WITH races AS (
  SELECT "800M" AS race,
    [STRUCT("Rudisha" as name, [23.4, 26.3, 26.4, 26.1] as splits),
     STRUCT("Makhloufi" as name, [24.5, 25.4, 26.6, 26.1] as splits),
     STRUCT("Murphy" as name, [23.9, 26.0, 27.0, 26.0] as splits),
     STRUCT("Bosse" as name, [23.6, 26.2, 26.5, 27.1] as splits),
     STRUCT("Rotich" as name, [24.7, 25.6, 26.9, 26.4] as splits),
     STRUCT("Lewandowski" as name, [25.0, 25.7, 26.3, 27.2] as splits),
     STRUCT("Kipketer" as name, [23.2, 26.1, 27.3, 29.4] as splits),
     STRUCT("Berian" as name, [23.7, 26.1, 27.0, 29.3] as splits)]
       AS participants)
SELECT
  race,
  participant
FROM races r
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(r.participants) as participant;
```

my sample output when i run the query above:

[image]

Comment: what exactly the question is here? your output is correct! and one in documentation is not!

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant but how do i get the output in the documentation? what should be the correct query? sorry i am new to bigQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do i get the output in the documentation? what should be the correct query?

Use below

```
SELECT
  race,
  TRANSLATE(FORMAT('%T', participant), '()"', '{}') AS participant 
FROM races r
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(r.participants) as participant
```

with output

[image]

Comment: thanks @MikhailBerlyant but why didnt the first unnest in the documentation work?

Comment: because documentation is written by humans like you and me. so "stuff happens" and either code was wrong or output is from another query!